# How to iterate over N files concurrently to count occurrence of unique word

Tags: go, file-handling

This is my code to count the occurrence of all the unique word in a file:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main(){
    file, err := os.Open("file1.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    words := make(map[string]int)
    /*asking scanner to split into words*/
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    count := 0
    //scan the inpurt
    for scanner.Scan() {
        //get input token - in our case a word and update it's frequence
        words[scanner.Text()]++
        count++
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
    }
    for k, v := range words {
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

I have to iterate this map over N files concurrently in order to calculate the occurrence of all the unique words.

Comment: Then the Tour of Go is a great start to learn and practice.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an [errgroup.Group](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group) to make it concurrent.

Keep in mind to handle concurrent writes to the map properly if you make it accessible for all goroutines.